# How do I install the firmware update to a Nikon camera?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, firmware

I downloaded a firmware update file from Nikon for D150. It was a compressed file that when I right click I have no option to open the file. I had already reformatted the card in the camera, but that Zip file wasn't seen by the camera. So I tried reformatting the card in the computer to a FAT filesystem, but it made no difference.

How do install the firmware update to my camera?

Comment: vtc b/c This question has no question.  Consider contacting Nikon tech support.

Comment: To my knowledge and the entries on Nikon page and wikipedia - there is no D150. Can you please check the model number? There is a W150 however....

Answer (score 1):

When you right click on the zip file, is there an option to "extract" all files?

**You need to unzip (extract the individual files contained within) the zip file first.** Then you can copy the firmware file from the results of the extraction to the camera's memory card. There's probably also a "read me" file that explains the entire procedure contained within the zip file.